# Linode VPS Metered Billing - How are hours calculated?

Tags: hosting, vps, billing, recurring-billing, linode

I was thinking of running my own game server. However, i only need it to be up when i want to play on it with my friends.

> If My Linode is Powered Off, Will I Be Billed?
>   If your Linode is powered off, but is still added as a service on your account, you will still be billed for it. This is because Linode maintains your saved data and reserves your ability to use other resources like RAM, transfer, etc. even when your Linode is powered off. You will be billed for any other active Linode service, such as Longview Pro or an extra IP, as well. If you want to stop being billed for a particular Linode service, you need to remove it from your account entirely.

With this in mind, lets say i create a stable game server and then save a disk image and then go on to destroy the Linode. When i want to use it i'll create the instance and then destroy again once im done.

Lets say i use it twice a week for 2 hours each time. With the Linode 2GB plan which charges at $0.015 per hour, Is it right to say that my total bill at the end of the month with amount to a fixed amount of 
`$0.015 x 2 x 4 = $0.12`

Documentation in this area has deem to be fuzzy. Looking to see if they are any additional cost not accounted for. If anyone has done it before please advise!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. Keep in mind a few things however:

- The hours are rounded up. If you go over by a minute you'll be charged for 3 hours.
- The time starts from when the Linode creation starts, not when you're actually able to SSH in.
- You may or may not eventually lose your images if your account has zero Linodes on it. DNS will also stop being served without any Linodes.